# How to pass command line arguments to Spring Batch

Tags: spring, shell, arguments, command, spring-batch

This is my first time working on a spring batch project. So I need to know how to pass arguments to the main class in a .sh file. The project is currently working and .sh file has a command line like this:

```
java -Xmx2048M -jar somebatch-SNAPSHOT.jar applicationContext.xml
```

And I want to pass arguments by changing this command. the project runs all jobs at the main class so job names are not specified in the command. What I want to do is pass arguments so I can select which jobs will run. Something like this:

```
java -Xmx2048M -jar somebatch-SNAPSHOT.jar --argument 1 applicationContext.xml
```

I don't need to pass the arguments to the jobParameters like `java -jar somejar.jar somejob value=1` as shown in some examples. I only need a value in the main class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to pass parameters on the cli with `-Dparam=value` and then in your main class do `System.getProperty("param")`? This is how I would do it in your case.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I ended up doing that and it does the job. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't need to pass the arguments to the jobParameters like java -jar somejar.jar somejob value=1 as shown in some examples. I only need a value in the main class.

In this case, you can pass parameters on the command line with `-Dparam=value` and then get them in your main class using `System.getProperty("param")`.

Comment: Great! and what about passing a param to the item reader? in this scenario, i must locate the file outside the jar and not adding it into src/main/resources